# How to populate table data from loop contains array of object with ngfor in angular 7

Tags: html, angular

I have a table whose data is coming from loop contains array of object.In which Status and loc again contains array of object,here I have populated in static way for Status and loc,but how to populate those field in dynamic way.Can any one please help me,here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<table class="table border">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index">
        <th>{{ column }}</th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index" >
          <td>{{row.name}}</td>
          <td>{{row.items}}</td>
          <td><span>{{row.Status[0].name}}</span>,<span>{{row.Status[1].name}}</span>,<span>{{row.Status[2].name}}</span></td>
          <td><span>{{row.loc[0].name}}</span>,<span>{{row.loc[1].name}}</span></td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component,ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
columns = ["name", "Items","status", "loc"];

  groups=[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "pencils",
        "items": "red pencil",
        "Status": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "green"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "red"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "yellow"
        }],
        "loc": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "loc 1"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "loc 2"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "loc 3"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "rubbers",
        "items": "big rubber",
        "Status": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "green"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "red"
        }],
        "loc": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "loc 2"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "loc 3"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "rubbers1",
        "items": "big rubber1",
        "Status": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "green"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "red"
        }],
        "loc": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "loc 2"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "loc 3"
        }]
    }

];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<table class="table border">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index">
                <th>{{ column }}</th>
            </ng-container>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index">
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            <td>{{row.items}}</td>
            <td>
                <span *ngFor="let item of row.Status;let j = index">
                    {{item.name}}
                    <span *ngIf="j != row.Status.length - 1">,</span></span>
           </td>
            <td>
                <span *ngFor="let item of row.loc;let k = index">
                   {{item.name}}
                   <span *ngIf="k != row.loc.length - 1">,</span>
                </span>     
           </td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See [Stackbiltz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vnrtz)